# Array Modifier Rotation

Tags: modifiers

[image]Hey guys I'm new to blender. I don't really know why this little dot is in the leaves instead of it being in the stem. Is there something I can do to move it or should I make a new one? I'm trying to make a plant but every time I use the Array modifier the leaf is the one that is intersecting with the empty instead of the stem[image]

Comment: that's the object's origin. see more in the documentation https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/origin.html

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the origin at the beginning of the leaf stem, to do that, select the vertices at the beginning of the leaf stem, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*:

[image]

Then back to *Object* mode, right click and *Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor*:

[image]

Now when you move and rotate your array's object:

[image]